# jquery selector for elements with only 1 child

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I need a jquery selector for elements with only 1 child.

so a list with a single list item will match but empty lists or lists with more than one list item will not.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$('li:only-child').parent();
```

?

[**Here is a demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Shef/uX65h/)

Answer (score 2):

```
$("ul").filter(function(){return $(this).children().length == 1; })
.addClass("someClass");
```

here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/JT5N2/

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("ul").filter(function(){ $(this).children().length == 1; });
```